# error: ‘string’ undeclared (first use in this function) gcc OS X

Tags: c, macos, gcc

```
$gcc a.c

string s = "string";

a.c:4: error: ‘string’ undeclared (first use in this function)


$gcc -v

Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no `string` datatype in C.

You probably want to use:

```
const char* s = "string";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `String` Data Structure as such in C. The general term we use as String is actually a `\0` terminated character array.

So here is what you can do

```
char *s = "string"
```

Or Maybe

```
char s[]="string"
```